# jQuery URI encode (char &) .html() attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read a lot of the HTML encoding post for the last day to solve this. I just managed to locate it.
Basicly I have set an attribute on an embed tag with jQuery. It all works fine in the browser.
No I want to read the HTML itself to add the result as a value for an input field to let the user copy & past it.

The **PROBLEM** is that the .html() function (also plain JS .innerHTML) converts the *'&' char* into *'& amp;' (without the space)*. Using differen html encoder functions doesnt make a difference. I need the '&' char in the embed code.
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="preview_small">
<object><embed src="main.swf?XY=xyz&YXX=xyzz"></embed>
</object></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#preview_small object").clone().html();
```

returns

```
... src=main.swf?XY=xyz&amp;YXX=xyzz ...
```

When I use:

```
$("#preview_small object").clone().children("embed").attr("src");
```

returns

```
main.swf?XY=xyz&YXX=xyzz
```

Any ideas how I can get the '&' char direct, without using regex after I got the string with .html()

Comment: Without the `&amp;` in the returned HTML string, it's not valid HTML.

Comment: Yes, with the &amp; it's not a valid HTML embed code that I can put on another site. I made it more clear.

Comment: No, you have it backwards. Without the `&amp;` it is not valid. The HTML example you have is being repaired by the browser, so when you convert the DOM into HTML you get `&amp;` back.

Comment: the & is part of a parameter list (separator) for a file to open in a embed code. Think of it as a youtube embedcode with a param list.
Every other char is not outputted in htmlentey just the &.

Comment: `var` is not a valid attribute of the [`embed`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element) element. The element was even deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Comment: oops this happened as I tried to make the code look simpler... the attribute is called "src" and the value is a *.swf that get some params with ?YX=value&YXX=value2. <embed src="main.swf?YX=value&YXX=value2 />
Sorry for confusing.

Comment: If the **value** is `foo&bar` then the expression of that value in **HTML** must be `foo&amp;bar`. `&amp;` is HTML for `&`. `&` is HTML for "This is the start of an entity". `src="main.swf?YX=value&YXX=value2"` is **wrong** the `&` must be written as `&amp;`. Confirm it with http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you very much for being that specific! I now got it. Just got confused as other like youtube are doing it wrong in their embed codes.  
  
For very one who want's to have a bit more detail:
http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the `&` char in the embed code.

No you don't. This:

```
<embed src="xyz&YXX=xyz"></embed>
```

is invalid HTML. It'll work in browsers since they try to fix up mistakes like this, but only as long as the string `YXX` doesn't happen to match an HTML entity name. You don't want to rely on that.

This:

```
<embed src="xyz&amp;YXX=xyz"></embed>
```

is correct, works everywhere, and is the version you should be telling your users to copy and paste.

> `attr("src")` returns `xyz&YXX=xyz`

Yes, that's the underlying value of that attribute. Attribute values and text content can contain almost any character directly. It's only the HTML serialisation of them where they have to be encoded:

```
<div title="a&lt;b&quot;&amp;c&gt;d">

$('div').attr('title') -> a<b"&c>d
```

> I want to read the HTML itself to add the result as a value for an input field

```
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>

$('#foo').val($('#preview_small object').html());
```

However note that the serialised output of `innerHTML`/`html()` is not in any particular fixed dialect of HTML, and in particular IE may give you code that, though generally understandable by browsers, is also not technically valid:

```
$('#somediv').html('<div title="a/b"></div>');
$('#somediv').html() -> '<DIV title=a/b></DIV>' - missing quotes
```

So if you know the particular format of HTML you want to present to the user, you may be better off generating it yourself:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

var src= 'XY=xyz&YXX=xyzz';
$('#foo').val('<embed src="'+encodeHTML(src)+'"><\/embed>');
```

(The `\/` in the close tag is just so that doesn't get mistaken as the end of a `<script>` block, in case you're in one.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice that .html() and innerHTML with the serialization output.

Comment: Just want every body know. If you're parsing params to an swf object in a HTML embed code, Flash only detects that it's a seperate value if you use the char '&'.